# How can I send the address of a wikipedia page but not the complete page?

Tags: wikipedia

In a wikipedia page, is there a way to catch just an article and not the total page ?

For example, in [this page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espace_d%C3%A9nombrablement_compact), I can send only the article **espace angélique** by adding #Espace_Angelique and thus will get directly [this article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espace_d%C3%A9nombrablement_compact#Espaces_ang%C3%A9liques). But in the previous link, I research **espace angélique** on google and google directly gave me the right link. When I'm on wikipedia, is there a way to catch directly the adress of an article or I have to add by hand the #blabla ?

Comment: Click on the section's title in the index ("Sommaire"). Btw, you're talking about "sections", not articles – article is the entire page.

Comment: @JJJ: Indeed, very nice :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, basically you need to mention the section you want to refer to.

**Linking to sections**

You can "deep link" to a section of an article (or other Wikipedia page), using a hash character (#), then the section's title, with underscore characters (_) replacing spaces. For example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitten#External_links links to the same section as Kitten#External links. However, be aware that section heading names are case sensitive (i.e. 'External' and 'external' are treated differently). Also, section headings may be renamed or deleted and so such links may break.

Reference : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Linking_to_Wikipedia

Answer (score 0):

The very simple way to handle this is by:

1. go to the table of content in the page
2. click on the section you want to reach in the TOC
3. simply copy the URL in the top bar of your browser

The URL in the top bar will be updated automatically to reach that specified section.